# setState in a nested array object for SectionList data by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, setstate, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to fill a SectionList with data from a SQLite database.

I start here:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        loading: true,
        sectionListData: [
          {
            title: 'A Bulls',
            data: []
          },
          {
            title: 'H Bulls',
            data: []
          },
          {
            title: 'C Bulls',
            data: []
          },
          {
            title: 'R Bulls',
            data: []
          }
        ]
      };
    }
```

I fetch the data from the database and when I go to setState to the appropriate place it doesn't take.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.aBulls();
    this.cBulls();
    this.hBulls();
    this.rBulls();
}
```

Each of the functions is built the same, fetching data from their respective database:

```
aBulls() {
  db.transaction(
    tx => {
    //SQL Statement
        tx.executeSql("select * from abulls group by reg",
    //Arguments
        [],
    //Success
        (tx, { rows: {_array} }) => {
          const handlebull = JSON.stringify(_array);
          const bulls = JSON.parse(handlebull);
          this.setState({sectionListData: [
            {
              0: 
                {
                  data: bulls
                }
            }
          ]
          });
          this.setState({loading: false});
        },
    //Error
        (error) => {console.log(error)}        
          );
      }
  )};
```

console.log(bulls) will return an array of data as expected.
console.log(this.state.sectionListData[0].data) will return 'undefined'.
I cannot see to get it to update  the index for the nested array for the SectionList.

Comment: When are you doing `console.log(this.state.sectionListData[0].data)`, you could pass a 2nd parameter function to `setState` and see what `this.state` looks after it's finished updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should set a local variable first to save the current state and then update the state from that local variable

```
aBulls() {
  db.transaction(
    tx => {
    //SQL Statement
        tx.executeSql("select * from abulls group by reg",
    //Arguments
        [],
    //Success
        (tx, { rows: {_array} }) => {
          const handlebull = JSON.stringify(_array);
          const bulls = JSON.parse(handlebull);
          let sectionListData = this.state.sectionListData;
          sectionListData[0].data = bulls;
          this.setState({sectionListData, loading: false});
        },
    //Error
        (error) => {console.log(error)}        
          );
      }
  )};
```

Comment: Works for me! Thank you so much, you made that look and sound so easy but I worked on it so long! Thank You!